# Can't sysprep generalize Windows 2016/2019 Datacenter Edition

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, azure-storage

I've created a VM on Azure and after installing all my software basics I'm trying to perform a `sysprep.exe`'s generalize and I'm getting the following error:

> A fatal error ocurred while trying to sysprep the machine

I've searched online for multiple solutions with no luck. Seems this is a "general" problem with not a single and working reply.
I executed the `slmgr /dlv` command and saw I'm supposed to have 1000 rearms left.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a clean installation and performing `sysprep` after each “basic software” installation, which uncovered a culprit.

One of my "software basics" included **Azure File Sync**, by Microsoft.

I installed the 10.1.0.0 version, which on the [interoperability notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-release-notes#interoperability) says:

> Running sysprep on a server that has the Azure File Sync agent
> installed is not supported and **can lead to unexpected results**. The
> Azure File Sync agent should be installed after deploying the server
> image and completing sysprep mini-setup.

Sysprep's error log:

> 2020-08-07 13:29:37, Error      [0x0f0085] SYSPRP LaunchDll:**Could not**
> **load DLL** C:\Program
> Files\ **Azure\StorageSyncAgent\AfsSysprepProvider.dll**[gle=0x0000007e]

And that's it. I simply need to install Azure File Sync after everything, including the `sysprep`. Hope it helps you.